# Getting a 404 on a private repo after adding a personal access token to .npmrc

Tags: github, npm, .npmrc

Not sure why this would be happening. Getting a

```
Request failed \"404 Not Found\""
```

I've created the token in my github settings, set the correct repository rights on the token, and then added it to my .npmrc file. In place of $TOKEN I've copied in the token itself. Am I missing something?

```
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=$TOKEN
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that package permissions weren't set up properly, not a problem on my end.